# Devise enable JSON sign in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, devise

I'm trying to enable devise JSON sign in while keeping the default "web" sign in as well in [this fresh app.](https://github.com/akashaggarwal7/deviseSimpleToken/commit/9846ad4311acd8a0ab8c07a3abf0c5eb132393fc) Apart from the changes in the commit that I linked to, the rest of the app is on default settings
(except in devise.rb, `config.http_authenticatable = true` and `config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = false`).

This is the request that I'm passing:

`curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in.json \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: 13b1a7b4-a55c-c776-94cb-2040a729133a' \
  -d '{"user_email": "blah@blah.com", "user_password": "changeme"}'`

(The postman token exists because I'm using postman directly, and not command line)

I also tried the same request as above for `http://localhost:3000/api/users/sign_in.json`

However, I'm still getting invalid CSRF error. Even if I add `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token` in my ApplicationController, I still get 401 with `{"error":"You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."}` response.

Digging deeper, I think that this response was generated because of devise, as the error message is in devise's locale file. However, I still don't understand how to fix the issue while also keeping the CSRF check enabled for non JSON requests(AFAIK CSRF can't be enabled for JSON requests).

Comment: Can you post your controller code?

Comment: @bhanu Thanks for looking in! You can find all of the code on the repository itself.